# How to remove range of git stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

I want to remove all stash'es, except most recent, from `git stash list`.

E.g. I want to remove stash *1* to *3* in a single git command:

```
stash@{0}: On master: Test related changes
stash@{1}: On master: Tets
stash@{2}: On master: Integrate bunyan logging and http2
stash@{3}: On master: Integrate bunyan logging and http2
```

I checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5737041/3878940, but its applicable to delete only a single stash. Is there any git command to delete a range of `stash`es?

Comment: Apparently the best answer is : no you cannot. Good question thought

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Slightly longer answer: no, but it's trivial.  You want to drop stashes 1, 2, and 3.  When you drop stash #1, stashes 2 and 3 become stashes 1 and 2 respectively.  When you drop the new stash #1, stash #2 (which was #3 originally) becomes stash #1.  Therefore, to drop three stashes, starting with #1, simply drop stash #1 three times.

Comment: Slight improvement to your answer. Rather, to avoid confusion and adjusting the stash id's while dropping, simply `git stash drop stash@{id}` in **descending order of id's**. So if you want to drop id's 1,2,3 : 'git stash drop stash@{3}' then 'git stash drop stash@{2}' and then 'git stash drop stash@{1}' .

Comment: @DhirajGandhi: that still causes the stash that was #4 to become #1, in the end. It may help you keep track of how many you have to go, though, in which case it may be of value.

Comment: torek: That's correct, but stash #4 won't be deleted in the end, so there is no problem with the answer of @DhirajGandhi.

Answer (score 31):

If you want to delete stash 1 to 3,just go to shell and type the following command:

```
for n in {1..3}
do
git stash drop stash@{1}   
done
```

Output

```
Dropped stash@{1} (79f369e9c4ce8348af8bd2da63f384cc7d02655e)
Dropped stash@{1} (744d2fc40e25f2db1bdc182d41f6eb9134957df4)
Dropped stash@{1} (7f9989207a675549866ab1fc7b15082eb4161e9f)
```

As git stash uses stack structure, each time you drop nth index, stack indexes decreases by 1. So eventually, you end up dropping stashes 1 to 3.
So, like this you can also drop a stash of length n just iterating like :

```
for n in {1..n}
do
git stash drop stash@{1}   
done
```

Comment: The `n` in `{1..n}` in this answer is a placeholder; literally putting `{1..n}` will only execute the drop once.

Comment: @jayqui it will keep dropping the stashes as I already explained that it uses stack structure, so whatever is at top, i.e. 1 here, it will keep dropping till n times.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Git on PowerShell you can get it easily. There is two approach to achieve this. (n is number of stash)

First approach,

```
for($i = 1; $i -lt n; $i++){ git stash drop "stash@{1}"}
```

Second approach,

```
for($i = n-1; $i -gt 0; $i--){ git stash drop "stash@{$i}"}
```

I assume you have countless stash, you can get count of stash (n) like this,

```
git stash list | measure-object -line
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly you want to drop all old stashes except the first one you can use a script like this:

```sh
for (( ; ; ))
do
    git stash drop stash@{1}
    Result = $?
    if [ Result != 0 ] 
    then
      break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

*POSIX* shell and variable range

```
#!/bin/sh
set -euo

for _ in `seq $1 $2`; do
    git stash drop stash@{$1}
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Now you can simply use this command in the terminal.

```
$ git stash clear
```

Comment: “Except most recent”

Comment: You might want to elaborate some steps either before or after doing the command that will help achieve the answer of the question so you're answer wont get down voted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).