# Can I force git to stash, even when there are no local changes

Tags: git, git-stash

I have a pre-push script in .git/hooks that does the following:

```
git stash -u
<build / test>
git stash pop
```

However, if the working directory is clean, then git stash -u does nothing, and no stash is created. Then pop pops the previous stash item. Is there a way of forcing stash?

A workaround is to create a temp file, that I then delete to force there to be something to stash.

Comment: You cannot stash if there's nothing to stash. You can, however, check if there are any unstaged changes, as discussed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3879077/7598462).

Comment: You could check if `git stash -u` creates a new entry.

Comment: I'm going to close as dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5737002/1256452 but note that since Git 2.9 there is also `git stash store`, which stores stashes created with `git stash create`. You can tell if `git stash create` created anything since it prints the hash ID; feed that to `git stash apply` to apply the stash. Note also `--keep-index` but note that there's a long standing bug with this.