# Git move latest commit on a branch to stash

Tags: git, commit, git-stash

When working on a git branch I got some changes in the latest commit. I suspect those changes to be wrong, but not sure. It is easy to remove the commit, and start over.

I want to move that commit to git-stash just incase I need them, and then try another solution on the branch, and still have the option to get the first commit back.

Comment: Why do you need stash? Create a new branch, rewind the old branch. (Or revert the commit)

Comment: That is much easier solution.

Comment: In fact, you should [stop using git stash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117335/23118) and use [temporary commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118) exclusively instead. Normal commits are much safer in they do not have [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737002/how-to-delete-a-stash-created-with-git-stash-create/5737041#comment27818770_5737041), [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48619276/23118) [quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75512773/23118) like stash have. –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a stash in this case, a regular branch works just fine.

```
git branch backup-my-work
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

`reset --hard HEAD^` will move your branch back by one commit and discard ALL changes in your working tree. Drop the `--hard` if you want to keep your local changes and the changes of the undone commit (you can then selectively remove the changes from your working tree)