# Can you get access to files git stashes if git stash pop refuses to merge?

Tags: git

How do I get access to data git stash refuses to merge

I ran

```
git stash      # two files not stashed since they were not in git yet
git stash -u   # add the sfiles to the stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Git refuses to un-stash because the pull has two files that were added with (-u untracked files)

```
error: could not restore untracked files from stash 
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again. 

git stash show 0
```

shows nothing.  Is there a way to get at the files given stash wont pop?  Is there a patch file in .git somewhere?

Comment: I wrote up an answer, but then I realized I may not fully understand your situation. Can you update your question with the output of `git stash list` and `git stash show -u`?

Comment: Sure, stashes consist of commits like any other. You can extract from them whatever you like. — But this is a good example of why I discourage use of stash. It's never really needed.

Comment: @larsks I'm not the OP but I wish you'd undelete your answer!

Comment: I've gone ahead and undeleted my answer.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and [stop using stash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117335/23118). By checking in your [temporary changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118) as *normal commits* you avoid all the [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737002/how-to-delete-a-stash-created-with-git-stash-create/5737041#comment27818770_5737041), [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48619276/23118) [quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75512773/23118) that stash have.

Comment: I appreciate stash may have issues, but you cant switch branch without it, you have to do something, and committing to the wrong branch is not a solution.  patching to /tmp works but that is really gits job

Comment: Commit and un-commit is a whole nother bag of cats :) I'd prefer to avoid, very easy to loose data that way.

Answer (score 3):

A stash is just a commit, so you can use regular tools like `git show` to access files in the stash. Let's say I have one unstaged change and one untracked file:

```
$ git status
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   README.md

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        example.txt
```

If I run `git stash -u`, I end up with a commit object named `refs/stash`:

```
$ git for-each-ref
54884038278578c80ed2aae843c74a38aafcebb7 commit refs/heads/main
879c8e21be397501fd4d9fd1440bff8fa79cc431 commit refs/stash
```

Unstaged changes (that is, changes to files that are tracked by git) are stored directly in `refs/stash`:

```
$ git show refs/stash
commit 879c8e21be397501fd4d9fd1440bff8fa79cc431
Merge: 5488403 cb7969c b3c4ebe
Author: Alice Example <alice@example.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 16 07:05:04 2024 -0500

    WIP on main: 5488403 Initial commit

diff --cc README.md
index b4f9938,b4f9938,0000000..b75fee6
mode 100644,100644,000000..100644
--- a/README.md
+++ b/README.md
@@@@ -1,1 -1,1 -1,0 +1,2 @@@@
  +This is an example of working with `git stash`.
+++This is an unstaged change
```

I can extract an individual file like this:

```
$ git show refs/stash:README.md
This is an example of working with `git stash`.
This is an unstaged change
```

Untracked files are stored in `refs/stash^3`:

```
$ git show refs/stash^3
commit b3c4ebed5f3566f37697c9adad2f15159a25c731
Author: Alice Example <alice@example.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 16 07:05:04 2024 -0500

    untracked files on main: 5488403 Initial commit

diff --git a/example.txt b/example.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..79d897a
--- /dev/null
+++ b/example.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+This is an untracked file
```

And I can extract files in a similar fashion:

```
$ git show refs/stash^3:example.txt
This is an untracked file
```

---

We can also check out the stash as a new branch. Using `git worktree` allows us to put this in a new directory. The following creates a new branch named `unstaged-changes` with the contents of `refs/stash^3` and checks it out into the `../unstaged-changes` directory:

```
$ git worktree add -b unstaged-changes ../unstaged-changes refs/stash^3
Preparing worktree (new branch 'unstaged-changes')
HEAD is now at b3c4ebe untracked files on main: 5488403 Initial commit
$ ls ../unstaged-changes/
example.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I needed    git show refs/stash:README.md

Comment: Iif "stash is just a commit" its weird that git stash cant merge it.  Patch files have no issues with merging whole new files.  Its difficult to see how pop even knows there is an issue.  its just a patch to merge with the current workspace in whatever state it is, no?